# Backbone JS Save/Delete to Server Keep Primary Keys Associated with Models?

Tags: database, backbone.js

Ok let's say I have a database with a Person table.  It has the following fields.

```
Id (PK, auto-increment) Name (string) Age (int)
```

I can fetch the server for a List of People and when I render the Backbone Views it will have their associated Ids in the model.  Great.

Now let's say I have an Add functionality to add a new Person.  I might have 2 text boxes (one for name, one for age) and a save button.

When I click save I could use my People Collection from Backbone and add that record to the collection and it will also handle (POST to the Backbone Collection URL) posting (name, age) to my server.

However the thing I'm not understanding is the Id that is generated from the database insert is no longer associated with the Backbone Model I just spun up.

Or is the idea that after ever "add" I need to fetch again to get a fresh list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may not have enough information to answer this based upon your question, so I'm presuming that you have a view that has been given a collection instance.  Further, I'm presuming that your POST posts the model's attributes, but returns the model's attributes right back including its newly-assigned id.

So what you want to do is:

1. Bind the view to the DOM event for whatever triggers the Person save.
2. Bind the view to the collection instance's add (and/or remove events).
3. In your Person save event handler, harvest the person attributes and initialize a new Person model with them; then save it.  In your success callback, add the resulting model, which now has an id into the collection.
4. In your add event handler, re-render the view as appropriate.

Here's some code:

```
PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
      "submit form#person-form" : "onSave",
      "click .remove-person"    : "onRemovePerson",
  },

  // Presumes you've handed the view a people collection and
  // named it 'collection' to enable backbone.js to auto set it
  // into the view's state.
  initialize: function(options) {
      _.bindAll(this, "onPersonAdded");
      this.collection.bind("add", this.onPersonAdded);
      this.collection.bind("remove", this.onPersonRemoved);
  },

  onSave: function(e) {
      var self = this;
      var person = new Person();
      var person_attrs = this.serialize();  // harvest from your form in this method.
      person.save(person_attrs, {
          success: function(saved_person, data) {
              self.collection.add(saved_person);
          },
          error: function(aborted_person, response) {
              // Error handling as needed.
          }
      });
  },

  onRemovePerson: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var cid = $(e.target).attr('id');
      var person = this.collection.getByCid(cid);
      person.destroy({
          success: function(removed_person, data) {
              self.collection.remove(removed_person);
          },
          error: function(aborted_person, response) {
              // Error handling as needed.
          }
      });
  },

  onPersonAdded: function(added_person) {
      // perform rendering as needed here.
  },

  onPersonRemoved: function(removed_person) {
      // perform rendering as needed here.
  }

});
```

As a stylistic note, you may not want to handle the model save code in the view.  You could alternatively defer to a controller or some other appropriate entity.

Comment: Bill - thanks for the reply. Seems you've been looking into Backbone a bit too recently.  Not quite sure it has me sold on a go to MVC JS framework just quite yet.  Although i do like a lot of what it brings to the table.

Comment: FWIW, we are building a 'touch' implementation of the TripCase (iPhone, Android, Blackberry) application using backbone.js.  As such, I"m accruing some experience with the framework.  Still learning for sure.

Comment: Cool - so the idea is post the Model to the server, wait for the call back, which will return including the newly spun up ID, then add to the collection which will trigger the view being re-rendered.  I think for this to work you would need 2 backbone JS views.  One view which represents a person record (maybe its an li element in a UL or a tr in a table) then an "App View" which handles Add and Add All.  do you agree?

Comment: I think you just need the one view which manages the collection.  You could definitely tease things into separate views, but consider the memory and file management concerns when doing so; in other words, you might choose to keep things simple.

Comment: With 1 view i'm not understanding how you do a "Remove".  At that point your View represents a collection, not a model.  So if you had a remove event inside your view, where do you get access to that particular model?

Comment: I've updated the code with what you might use to manage the removal.  It assumes that you use a Person instance's cid as a unique identifier in the DOM for each Person.  You could get the id from the DOM, its just that it would contain the cid.  Then you use the built in backbone.js method to get the person by the cid.  Thereafter, you destroy the person.  I've added event responders to use an event-based approach for the view to update itself when a remove happens.  This approach means that the view could handle person removals that happened not necessarily through form DOM events.